# RecyclerView Adapter gives in out cannot be converted to List<>

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My Adapter class gives me errors:

> List< DataAimsAdapter > cannot be converted to List< AimsFragmentRecycler
>
> constructor DataAimsAdapter in class DataAimsAdapter cannot be applied
> to given types; required: Context,List found:
> String,String,int reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in
> length

Class where should realize RecyclerView

```
import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
    import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
    import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.List;

public class AimsBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    List<DataAimsAdapter> tab = new ArrayList<DataAimsAdapter>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aims, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View showModalBottomSheet =  (View) RootView.findViewById(R.id.as_modal);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        // создаем адаптер
        DataAimsAdapter adapter = new DataAimsAdapter(getActivity(),tab);
        // устанавливаем для списка адаптер
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        setInitialData();
        return RootView;

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

        private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        };


        @Override
        public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
            super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
            View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.aims_dialog_modal, null);
            dialog.setContentView(contentView);
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
            CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
            if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
                ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
            }
        }
    private void setInitialData(){

        tab.add(new DataAimsAdapter ("Huawei P10", "Huawei", R.drawable.notepad));
        tab.add(new DataAimsAdapter ("Elite z3", "HP", R.drawable.flag));
        tab.add(new DataAimsAdapter ("Galaxy S8", "Samsung", R.drawable.notebook));
        tab.add(new DataAimsAdapter ("LG G 5", "LG", R.drawable.time));
    }
    }
```

Adapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class DataAimsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAimsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<AimsFragmentRecycler> tab;

    DataAimsAdapter(Context context, List<AimsFragmentRecycler> tab) {
        this.tab = tab;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }



    @Override
    public DataAimsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aims_fragment_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAimsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AimsFragmentRecycler phone = tab.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
        holder.nameView.setText(phone.getName());
        holder.companyView.setText(phone.getCompany());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tab.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView nameView, companyView;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_tittle);
            companyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_of_tap
    }
}
```

Class Constructor

```
public class AimsFragmentRecycler {

    private String name_tittle;
    private String text_of_tap;
    private int image;

    public AimsFragmentRecycler(String name_tittle, String text_of_tap, int image){

        this.name_tittle=name_tittle;
        this.text_of_tap = text_of_tap;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name_tittle;
    }

    public void setName(String name_tittle) {
        this.name_tittle = name_tittle;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return this.text_of_tap;
    }

    public void setCompany(String text_of_tap) {
        this.text_of_tap = text_of_tap;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

XML's Adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_tittle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_of_tap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `setInitialData` function you have `new DataAimsAdapter` where you should have `new AimsFragmentRecycler` instead. You're instantiating the wrong class. Then your tab list should be of type `AimsFragmentRecycler` instead of `DataAimsAdapter`.

Comment: I'm not saying this will fix *all* your problems, but should get to closer to the right direction :D